# Android 8.0 source code build error "xxx" depends on undefined module "libxxx"

Tags: android, build

I have downloaded the Android O preview version with the following steps:

1. repo `init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b refs/heads/android-o-preview-2`
2. repo sync

And then,start to build the source code:

1. source build/envsetup.sh
2. lunch 1
3. make -j8

When the building is running ,after some seconds, this build error happened:

[image: Build Error Message]

I don't know why, I tried to fix the dependency for system libs, but it does not work yet.

Answer (score 0):

android-o-preview-2 is not a buildable branch, switch to master or something else